# MSSQL mirroring error 1499

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I`ve got a problem with my mirroring. I have already uses this feature to make 2 db work.
But it was on test bases. 
Now when I use my scripts on work DB it throws an error:

```
Msg 1499, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Database mirroring error: status 1488, severity 16, state 1, string db_name.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you database may be in single user mode

right click the database -> options and select MULTI USER under restrict access

Comment: of course my principal is in single user mode...otherwise how can I make them be exactly the same while work db are constantly changing.
Are you sure that is it because of SM?

Comment: its the mirror database that needs to be in single user, not the principal

Comment: mirror db must be exact the same as principal. Once principal changes, I must backup it again. So I made it in SM.

Comment: agree but you said that the principal is in single mode, but is the mirror who need to be in single mode

Comment: so I need to put both db in SM, set partners and set principal in MM?

Comment: Ok, let’s review the terms. As I understand (and I may be wrong myself, it’s been a while since I don configure it) on DB mirroring, you “mirror” one DB to another (let’s ignore  witnesses servers, because honestly I’ve never used them). The main DB, the one  your app connects to, is called “principal” and the “backup” DB is called “mirror”.  Both of them are also called “partners” on a mirroring configuration. So the mirroring will apply every change made on “principal” to the  “mirror”.  To achieve that, the principal DB should be in Multi User and the mirror DB in Single User.

Comment: yes, thats true, but SM on mirror is optional, its already inaccessible. I mean, that while I setting partners, to avoid resynchronization I put principal into SM. Does this action become the result of this 1499 error?

Comment: but is your principal database Multi User?

Comment: OK I will set it MM and close all connections except mine.
Will it be helpful? I ask because to test it I need to stop business process and its complicated)

Answer (score 0):

try to check the principal and mirror server names, dtabase name etc. It is possible that there is misprints.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to us recently.  We found that SQL set the restored database to single user mode during the restore process.

After some research, we simply restarted SQL server services on the mirror.  When SQL started back up, the restored database was in multi-user mode and we were able to initialize mirroring without any issues.

There are other sites out there with answers as well, but they involve taking down the principle database.  That was not really an option for us at the time.  Here is one example in case restarting the mirror does not help the next person who runs into this.

http://blog.armgasys.com/?p=259

Answer (score 0):

I had some what similar issue this is how I solved it.  When I ran wizard for mirroring it created endpoints(first part) successfully but when i tried to turn on mirroring it gave me error.
So  I solved it by running below command on both server

```
USE [master]
alter database [yourdatabase] set partner off;
go
```

--Secondary already had partner but primary did not

--- then i ran below commands on each server.

```
USE [master]
ALTER DATABASE [yourdatabase]
SET PARTNER = 'TCP://OtherMachineSQLname.domain.LOCAL:5022';
GO
```

-- then mirroring started to work.